# Upload GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE to a GL_FLOAT texture

Tags: c++, opengl

I have an OpenGL texture that is created normally, using `GL_FLOAT` as its data type:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F, Dims.x, Dims.y, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, Data);
```

(`Data` is sent properly as a `float` array.)

I then have to update the texture using data that is in the form of unsigned bytes. Is it legal to update the texture with `glTexSubImage2D` using `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`?

```
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, Dims.x, Dims.y, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NewData);
```

(`NewData` is sent as `unsigned char*`.)

The documentation does not appear to mention anything about using different data types between these functions. Is it possible to update the texture this way, or would the texture data have to be converted to `float*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In desktop OpenGL<sup>*</sup>, so long as the [pixel transfer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer) [format](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer_Format) is of the same kind as the [internal format](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format), the transfer will work. By "kind", I mean the two formats have to be talking about the same kind of data. You can't upload depth pixel data to a color internal format. And if the internal format is an integer format, then the pixel transfer format must be one of the `_INTEGER` versions.

But other than that, the sky's the limit... as long as you don't like performance. But it's not like you sending `GL_FLOAT` data to a `16F` texture was particularly fast either.

<sup>*</sup>: I mention desktop OpenGL because OpenGL ES specifically *requires* the formats to match. Because they like performance ;)